# Passing index from ng-container to ng-template

Tags: angular, primeng

I wanna pass the index from an ***ngFor** to and `ng-container` to `ng-template`.
But it seems not working

```
                  <p-accordionTab *ngFor="let title of titleItems; let i = index;" class="mb-2" [selected]="true">
                            <p-header>
                                {{title}}
                                <span *ngIf="title.help" tooltip="{{title.help}}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                                </span>
                            </p-header>
                            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleTemplate; context: {$implicit: { index: i}}"></ng-container>
                        </p-accordionTab>
                    </p-accordion>

                 <ng-template #titleTemplate let-index>
                    <form [formGroup]="domandeFormGroup" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-left">
                        <div> 
                            <input formControlName="order-{{index}}"
                                    class="title-input-border form-control" type="text">
                          </div> 
                    </form>
                 </ng-template>
```

What is wrong?? It's seems that not passing the index

> Cannot find control with name: 'order-'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make 2 changes:

- `context: {index: i}`
- `let-index="index"`

Try like this:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleTemplate; context: {index: i}"></ng-container>


<ng-template #titleTemplate let-index="index">
</ng-template>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-forms-primeng-sublevels-lprmrd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: good job , can you give more information about **ngTemplateOutlet** is possible 

Comment: Sure, I thought since he has used it, he must be aware